# declare a form as delegate

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates

I have 4 forms in my program:

- StartForm
- UIForm1
- UIForm2
- DebugForm

I start the program with StartForm, then user can use buttons to start UIForm1 and 2. There is also another form called DebugForm that there is a textBox in it and I put all errors duruing using UIForm1 and 2 inside it (Exceptions and etc..).

No I want to declare DebugForm in StartForm so UIForm1 and 2 can both access it. How can I do it? I tried declaring it as public but it cant be accessed:

```
//in StartForm
public DebugForm dFrm = new DebugForm(); //Not working

//in UIForm1 or 2
//add a error to textbox
dFrm.textBox.Text += "ERROR NUMBER 1"; //Not working
dFrm.Show(); //Not working
```

I suspect I have to do it somehow with delegate keyword. How it will be possible to do so?

Comment: Please include fuller code examples (we don't know whether this code is all in a method etc) and provide more details than "Not working". The compiler error message would help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick-fix would be to declare the DebugForm variable in StartForm as:

```
//in StartForm
public static DebugForm dFrm = new DebugForm();
```

And use it in your other forms as:

```
StartForm.dFrm.textBox.Text += "ERROR NUMBER 1";
StartForm.dFrm.Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

A clean way to do this without actually exposing StartForm to UIForms1, 2 would be to change UIForm1 and 2's constructor to take an action.

```
private Action<string> _showDebugForm;
public UIForm1(Action<string> showDebugForm)
{
 _showDebugForm = showDebugForm
}
```

and call

```
 if(_showDebugForm!=null)
 {
     _showDebugForm("ERROR NUMBER 1");
 }
```

in UIForm1

And when you create UIForm1, 2 do something like this

```
new UIForm1(str =>
{
    dFrm.textBox.Text += str;
    dFrm.Show();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

A delegate is a "pointer" to a method, so it represents the function that it is being assigned or multiple methods.  It cannot be used to represent an object.

Why don't you create a collection with string objects (List) in it and then when you create your debug form you can empty it out in the textbox.

You create the collection in your mainForm and pass it to the UI1 & 2 forms.  When you then create your DebugForm you can pass it there and do whatever you like.

You could create a property in each form to which you can assign this collection.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a public property in `StartForm` thats provides access to `DebugForm`

```
public class MainForm
{
    private DebugForm debugForm = new DebugForm();

    public DebugForm DebugForm
    {
        get { return this.debugForm; }
    }        
}
```

Then you can access `DebugForm` through `StartForm.DebugForm`

```
startForm.DebugForm.Show();
startForm.DebugForm.TextBox.Text += "Error";
```